# Uploading Excel files to dropbox?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file I am creating using ExcelWriter via pandas.

Here is what I have so far:

```
output = BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='raw_data', index=False)
df_totals.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='totals', index=False)
writer.save()
output.seek(0)
dbx.files_upload(output, 'my_path/test.xlsx')
```

It is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class '_io.BytesIO'>
```

The file_upload method takes bytes as input so I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [the docs](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload), `files_upload` expects a bytes object, not a BytesIO object.

The following should work:

```
dbx.files_upload(output.getvalue(), 'my_path/test.xlsx')
```