# Python convert StringIO to binary

Tags: python, pandas, dropbox, stringio

I have a simple task: in luigi, store pandas dataframe as a csv in dropbox, using dropbox-python sdk

Usually (with S3, for example) you can use StringIO as a file-like in-memory object. It also works great with pandas `df.to_csv()`

Unfortunately, dropbox sdk requires binary type, and I can't get how to translate StringIO into binary:

```
with io.StringIO() as f:
    DF.to_csv(f, index=None)
    self.client.files_upload(f, path=path, mode=wmode)

TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class '_io.StringIO'>
```

ByteIO won't work with the `df.to_csv()` ...

Comment: Try to coerce the `BytesIO` to a string with `str()`?

Comment: Well I actually need the opposite - pandas requires stringIO, and I need to convert the result to binary for the `dropbox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459197/7738328) answer, dropbox expects a bytes object, not a file, so converting to `BytesIO` will not help. However, the solution is simpler than that. All you need to do is encode your string as binary:

```
csv_str = DF.to_csv(index=None) # get string, rather than StringIO object
self.client.files_upload(csv_str.encode(), path=path, mode=wmode)
```